# exp:channel:form date undefined with datepicker

Tags: forms

I updated today one of our EE installation from 2.6.1 to 2.7.2 and one of the changes was going from safecracker to EE forms.

All working well except when I use date picker for entry date and closing date. Entry date, by default formatting looks ok, but as soon as I change the date it appear with undefined (example: **2013-11-12un12efine12**). Same happens to Expiry date as well.

I've added the css as required and it seems fine:

```
<link href="{path=css/_ee_channel_form_css}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />
```

and it starts with

```
{exp:channel:form channel="jobs" return="/jobs/booking/ENTRY_ID"  include_jquery="yes"}
```

And I believe this is correct as well.

This is the page http://www.youthworks.net/jobs/booking

If anyone have an idea where something is wrong, I would love to hear from you.

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

It might be this bug: https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19782
which affected me, and the fix worked as well:

> Known Solution:
>   -------------- Try editing system/expressionengine/modules/channel/libraries/Channel_form/Channel_form_lib.php
>   around line 966 so it looks like:
>
> ```
> if ($this->datepicker)
>   {
>    $js_defaults['ui'][] = 'datepicker';
>    $js_defaults['file'][] = 'cp/date';
>
>   }
> ```
>
> You’re just adding the $js_defaults[‘file’][] = ‘cp/date’;.